# HTML5 Canvas - Radius of the Donut chart is more than the Input value

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to implement Donut chart using Html5 canvas. The problem is the radius of the Donut is more that what i gave.

I passed the following values , `dmbChart(125,125,100,25,values,colors,labels,0);` to the function `dmbChart(cx,cy,radius,arcwidth,values,colors,labels,selectedValue)`, where cx and cy are the center of circle in X and Y axis. I'm getting a donut with bigger radius.

When i pass the values  `dmbChart(100,100,100,25,values,colors,labels,0);` to the function, the donut should touch the Div container on 2 sides, because theres 100px of width and height gap from the container to the center of the circle which is equal to the radius of the donut chart. But its getting out of the Div.

Working code: https://jsfiddle.net/nvarun123/yn1bhj2a/5/

Html code:

```
<canvas id="canvas" class="cont" width="250px" height="250px"></canvas>
```

JavaScript code:

```
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx=canvas.getContext("2d");

var colors=['green','orange'];
var values=[47,53];
var labels=['Completed','Pending'];

dmbChart(125,125,100,25,values,colors,labels,0);

function dmbChart(cx,cy,radius,arcwidth,values,colors,labels,selectedValue){
    var tot=0;
    var accum=0;
    var PI=Math.PI;
    var PI2=PI*2;
    var offset=-PI/2;
    ctx.lineWidth=arcwidth;
    for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){tot+=values[i];}
    for(var i=0;i<values.length;i++){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(cx,cy,radius,
            offset+PI2*(accum/tot),
            offset+PI2*((accum+values[i])/tot)
        );
        ctx.strokeStyle=colors[i];
        ctx.stroke();
        accum+=values[i];
    }
    var innerRadius=79;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(cx,cy,innerRadius,0,PI2);
    ctx.fillStyle=colors[selectedValue];

    ctx.fill();
    ctx.textAlign='center';
    ctx.textBaseline='bottom';
    ctx.fillStyle='white';
    ctx.font=(60)+'px verdana';
    ctx.fillText(values[selectedValue],cx,cy+innerRadius*.7);
    ctx.font=(20)+'px verdana';
    ctx.fillText(labels[selectedValue],cx,cy-innerRadius*.25);
}
```

Can anyone tell me whats the problem.

Comment: I think it's because of the arcWidth. `dmbChart(125,125,112.5,25,values,colors,labels,0);` seems to work as the radius takes into account half of the arcWidth.

Comment: If i remove the arcWidth, then the outer circle of the donut chart is not visible. Any other way to solve this.

Comment: Don't remove the arcWidth, just fiddle with the radius until it makes the circle touch the edges. Set the radius to 112.5. Unless I'm misunderstanding the problem.

Comment: Oh, I see. You want it to touch on two sides. So make it `dmbChart(112.5,112.5,100,25,values,colors,labels,0);`

Comment: Got it thanks for your help